# Leveling the base for a hot tub?

Tags: hot-tub

A lot of outdoor concrete slabs / patios have a slope for drainage. If you put a hot tub in such a location obviously it would also be out of level.

**Is there any standard or recommended way to level the slab base** prior to installing the hot tub?

I have scanned around and there are numerous internet suggestions - but ideally I'd like to know if there is either a standard "best practice" method and/or something recommended by hot tub manufacturers.

Examples of suggestions I've read each of which has some obvious *potential* but maybe avoidable problems:

- Shim with angled bits of wood (susceptible to rot, movement)
- Sand (could move/erode)
- Build up additional concrete (poor bonding, spalling, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: How unlevel is it?  Typical portable hot tubs are about 7’x 7’, how much slope do you have in that area?

Comment: It is about 1/8" per foot which I think is typical. Or about a 1% slope...